# import filters - TypeError: type() doesn't support MRO entry resolution

Tags: python

*Python 3.7.1, filters 1.3.2*

```
>>> import filters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\filters\__init__.py", line 27, in <modu
    from filters.extensions import FilterExtensionRegistry
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\filters\extensions.py", line 11, in <mo
    from class_registry import EntryPointClassRegistry
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\class_registry\__init__.py", line 5, in
    from .registry import *
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\class_registry\registry.py", line 33, i
    class BaseRegistry(with_metaclass(ABCMeta, Mapping)):
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 827, in __new__
    return meta(name, bases, d)
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\abc.py", line 126, in __new__
    cls = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)
TypeError: type() doesn't support MRO entry resolution; use types.new_class()
```

Looks like it is related to [this](https://bugs.python.org/issue33188) and got fixed. However, I have the *latest Python 3.7* and filters package. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `filters`?

Comment: @HåkenLid https://pypi.org/project/filters/

Comment: Hey @stkubr maintainer of the filters project here; just saw your issue.  This is caused by https://github.com/eflglobal/class-registry/issues/9 — working on a fix today 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maintainer of filters and class-registry here.  I apologise that it took me so long to find this!

The issue is caused by a couple of lines in the class-registry package:

```
class BaseRegistry(with_metaclass(ABCMeta, Mapping)):
    ...

class MutableRegistry(with_metaclass(ABCMeta, BaseRegistry)):
    ...
```

The error occurs because `with_metaclass()` creates a dynamic type internally, which conflicts when using it with a generic type like `Mapping` and `MutableMapping`.

This issue was discussed on https://bugs.python.org/issue33188 and it appears that the outcome was, "works as intended":

> This is not a bug but an explicit design decision. Generic classes are *static* typing concept and therefore are not supposed to work freely with *dynamic* class creation. During discussion of PEP 560 it was decided that there should be at least one way to dynamically create generic classes, `types.new_class` was chosen for this, see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0560/#dynamic-class-creation-and-types-resolve-bases
>
> Also the exception message is quite clear about this. Unfortunately, PEPs 560 and 557 were discussed in parallel so not every possible interactions where thought out. But is it critical for dataclasses to call `type`? I believe there should be no other differences with `types.new_class`. I would say the latter is even better than `type` because it correctly treats `__prepare__` on the metaclass IIRC. So I would propose to switch from `type()` to `types.new_class()` for dynamic creation of dataclasses.

There are two possible ways to resolve this issue:

1. Use `add_metaclass()` instead of `with_metaclass()`.
2. Drop support for Python 2 and replace `with_metaclass()` with Python-3-style base/metaclass declarations.

Both solutions are represented in [pull requests](https://github.com/eflglobal/class-registry/pulls) submitted by [stj](https://github.com/stj).

I no longer work at EFL Global [now LenddoEFL], so I don't have direct access to that repo any more.  It may be some time before a new version is released; in the meantime, I have forked the project and released a new version that explicitly supports Python 3.7 (and drops support for Python 2):

https://pypi.org/project/phx-filters/